# GEE exporting images in loop: description fails

Tags: google-earth-engine

I think this might be a very simple fix but I can't figure it out.
I'm trying to export images in a loop to Google drive, so the filename/description should be updated in each loop.

```
    for (var i= 0;i<15;i++) {
    var day = i*10
    var s2exp =  s2Filt.filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(fromDayOfYear+day,toDayOfYear+day)) 
    var s2composite = s2exp.median().clip(geometry); 
    var start = fromDayOfYear+day
    var end = toDayOfYear+day
    var desc = ee.String('image').cat(ee.Number(start)).cat(ee.Number(end));
    print(desc)
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: s2composite,
      description: ee.String(desc) ,
      folder: 'hardanger_s2',
      scale: 100
    });
    }
```

Printing the description works fine and I get a string like image101110. But when I try to trigger the task, it doesn't work because the task name and filename look like this:

ee.String({  "type": "Invocation",  "arguments": {    "string1": {      "type": "Invocation",      "arguments": {        "string1": "image",        "string2": {          "type": "Invocation",          "arguments": {            "input": 101          },          "functionName": "String"        }      },      "functionName": "String.cat"    },    "string2": {      "type": "Invocation",      "arguments": {        "input": 110      },      "functionName": "String"    }  },  "functionName": "String.cat"})

Can anyone help me figure out what went wrong here? Complete code is at the link below.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c817cbb307fde9f62baf6187136ad21c?accept_repo=users%2Fopenmrv%2FMRV

Answer (score 1):

For full disclosure, this is my question and I managed to figure out my password in the meantime (and now I can't get back into this temporary account!)

Solution: I added
var desc = (desc.getInfo())